# Are there any size limitations in SSIS package files?

Tags: ssis

I'm currently searching for physical size limitation of a DTSX file. We lose someting proporties, and is seems that it's only appening to quite big DTSX file (+5Mb)

Does anyone have a good link or advise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a dtsx file whose size grows to 5 MB, I can only imagine that the process flow in the file itself is monstrously large. When SSIS tries to load too many jobs within a single package, it puts strains on the reserved resources for that package. I would recommend breaking your package up into several smaller packages each focused on one particular area of functionality, and creating one master package to launch the sub packages in order.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible, as each package has to wait end of previous package before starting next one.

Comment: SSIS allows you to run any tasks in sequence (through precedence constraints) or in parallel (by removing precedence constraints inside a sequence container). This includes Execute Package Tasks.