# how to redirect values from one package to another package in ssis

Tags: ssis

With reference to this question [Limitations in SSIS package files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781281/are-there-any-size-limitations-in-ssis-package-files) I decided to use **"Sequence"** and **"Execute Package Task"** to split my task in two files but my problem is that how to contino from the same place package 1 finished. what I mean is if we suppose to do some changes on data, how to lead data to another package without storing data in db? (I am talking about many number of row data not a single parameter)

Is there any way to do it? I couldn't find any tutorial about it, I would appreciate if there is any share with me.

This image can explain what I am looking for to do.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to send buffer data from one data flow to another, you need to store the data somewhere.

Luckily it is quite easy to do that. You can store data in a [raw file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/raw-file-destination). Should be faster than writing to SQL tables. Pass the file location to the next package via a parameter and parameterize the Raw File Source there to use it.

If you only need to perform lookups against your data, you can use cache transformations. [Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/Compudicted/archive/2012/03/10/ssis-2012-how-to-share-cache-among-multiple-packages.aspx) you can find a nice tutorial about sharing cached data among packages.

Comment: is it recommended for huge volume of data?

Comment: SSIS handles huge volumes of data quite nicely inside the data flow using buffers which are held in RAM memory (it splits the data into smaller parts and process a few rows at a time). In your case I would say there is no other way than writing the data to disk, because I assume that you will not be able to hold all of the data in RAM in an object-type variable at once while switching to the next package. I do not know which would be better - SQL server table or a raw file, you need to check. I would bet on a raw file.

Comment: Do you have any experience in Talend? if yes, do you recommend SSIS or Talend?

Comment: No, sorry, I've never used Talend.

Answer (score 1):

You could store your multi-row data in an SSIS Object-type variable and share the variable between packages.

Comment: can you explain a bit more? Any good tutorial to follow? is it recommended for huge volume of data?